# Force overwrite on master from a pull request?

Tags: git, github

I've got a pull request on GitHub that's dramatically different than my master (total redesign of the web app) and want to force it to be used as master. It can't automatically be merged because it's so different, but it's the version I want to use as master.

Is there a way to force an overwrite of master with the PR?

It's also a branch in the main repo, so if not could I rename that branch to master and get rid of the old master somehow?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite your current history with the PR branch:

```
git fetch <URL of fork>
git push -f origin fork/pr-branch:master
```

Beware that this will blow away your history and break all forks.

Comment: Not too worried about breaking forks as I'm the only one who messes with this stuff. That said, it would be nice to retain some kind of history on the old version of the site. Maybe create a new branch containing just that, then have master go to the PR branch.